# How do I solve this SSLError using Python and requests?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, openssl, pycharm, linux-mint

In Linux Mint, running Pycharm, using the requests library/package gives me an error when I run this code:

```
import requests

r = requests.get("https://www.wikipedia.org/")

print(r)
```

The error I get is:

```
raise SSLError(
urllib3.exceptions.SSLError: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.
```

I tried [this](https://kodlogs.com/39168/cant-connect-to-https-url-because-the-ssl-module-is-not-available) solution as it was one of the only suggestions I could find that didn't include (ana)conda since I'm not using that.

Additional info on what I'm using:

- Python 3.9.1 virtual environment (Poetry)
- Pycharm 2021.1.1
- Openssl is already the newest version (1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.3)

If there's any additional information I need to provide I'd be glad to!

Comment: How did you install Python-3.9.1? For web scraping you do not need the latest python version, so you may want to use system (Ubuntu) python, so you are sure that python is linked with the correct and expected libraries. Else: check that you downloaded python for the correct distribution (and ev. check to install older openssl [you should be able to install parallel version of openssl]

Comment: I created a Python executable with Pyenv. Then I created a virtual environment off of that executable using Poetry. I've never had any problems using this method but your suggestion sounds reasonable and I haven't thought about that myself, thank you!